# How to handle multi environment builds?

Tags: java, git, maven, tomcat, deployment

I am working for a relatively small consultancy company, which delivers java enterprise web applications for big companies.
In a recent meetup with the customer I developed some ideas on how to tailor our release process to their way of working.

For each application platform they usually have a dev, test and production environment on which our applications are deployed. Additionally we have a local development environment, in which we do most of our development.

Our current approach is that we have 4 sets of configuration data, one for each environment. If we prepare a release for one of the environments, we exchange the configuration and use maven to generate the war file for deployment on a tomcat server. Furthermore, we use a git for version control.

I want to automate this process into one overall build process, but would appreciate some feedback  on which approach to take:

**Configuration**

- Should the configuration integrated into the build as part of the war file or externalised and feed into the web application? How could this be realised using maven?
- How do you handle the difference of multi-platform configurations? (e.g. a flag based approach as part of the build process)

**Artefact generation**

- My goal is to deliver an rpm for each environment instead of a war file, such that I can control the installation path and make the installation reversible. Is this a common practice?

**Version Control**

- We use git for version control, with a dev, stage and release branch in a single repository. Currently we also store all of the platform configurations into the same repository, which in my opinion has nothing to do with the dev/stage/release branch. Does it make sense to put into a separate repository?

Comment: Just a hint [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19637787/using-maven-to-build-multiple-resources-assemblies-that-are-very-similar).

Answer (score 0):

If this is compile time configuration - you can drive using something.properties file and let ant / maven decide based on various properties.

If configuration is run time, it you can drive it thru respective web.xml or similar files