# Using maven to build multiple resources assemblies that are very similar

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I'm having a problem with this very redundant maven configuration.

The application I'm working on sometimes gets built for environments that need alternate resource bundles. The current way the resources are prepared for deployment is that they are added to a single .zip file. The build master then deploys the zipped resources to the server. For some environments, alternate versions of some of the resources need to be used. The folder structure in the project looks like this:

```
src/main/resources
  - resource1
  - resource2
  - resource2
  ENV1/
    -resource1 (environment-specific)
  ENV2/
    -resource1 (environment-specific)
    -resource3 (environment-specific)
```

For most environments, the resource zip file needs to contain the files `resource1`, `resource2`, `resource3`. For `ENV1`, the zip file needs to contain `ENV1/resource1`, `resource2`, `resource3`. For `ENV3`, the zip file needs `ENV2/resource1`, `resource2`, `ENV2/resource3`.

I am currently doing this with an assembly descriptor for each environment, and a separate execution in my POM file:

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>zip-normal-resources</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <descriptor>assembly-descriptor.xml</descriptor>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>zip-ENV1-resources</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <descriptor>assembly-descriptor-ENV1.xml</descriptor>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
```

And each descriptor looks very similar. The "normal" assembly desrciptor:

```
<assembly
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 "
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance "
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2
                         http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd ">
    <id>Resources</id>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>*.properties</include>
                <include>*.xml</include>
            </includes>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <filtered>true</filtered>
        </fileSet>

        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.build.outputDirectory}/resources</directory>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*</include>
            </includes>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

An environment-specific descriptor:

```
<assembly
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 "
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance "
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2
                         http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd ">
    <id>Resources-ENV1</id>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>*.properties</include>
                <include>*.xml</include>
            </includes>
                    <!-- exclude environment-specific files -->
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>resource1</exclude>
                    </excludes>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <filtered>true</filtered>
        </fileSet>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>src/main/resources/ENV1</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>*.properties</include>
                <include>*.xml</include>
            </includes>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <filtered>true</filtered>
        </fileSet>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.build.outputDirectory}/resources</directory>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*</include>
            </includes>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

This solution works but it feels very inefficient. I don't like having multiple assemblies for each environment that are almost identical, except for the environment names. Is there any way to streamline this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming the following structure:

```
src/
└── main
    ├── assembly
    │   └── iterator.xml
    └── environment
        ├── dev
        │   └── server.properties
        ├── pretest
        │   └── server.properties
        ├── production
        │   └── server.properties
        ├── qa
        │   └── server.properties
        └── test
            └── server.properties
```

where you can use the following assembly-descriptor like this:

```xml
<assembly>
  <id>${item}</id>
  <formats>
    <format>war</format>
  </formats>
  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
  <dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
      <unpack>true</unpack>
      <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
    </dependencySet>
  </dependencySets>
  <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
      <outputDirectory>WEB-INF</outputDirectory>
      <directory>${basedir}/src/main/environment/${item}/</directory>
      <includes>
        <include>**</include>
      </includes>
    </fileSet>
  <fileSet>
      <outputDirectory>WEB-INF</outputDirectory>
      <directory>${project.build.directory}/environment/${item}</directory>
      <includes>
        <include>**</include>
      </includes>
  </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

using the [iterator-maven-plugin](http://khmarbaise.github.io/iterator-maven-plugin/) will solve the problem:

```xml
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.soebes.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>iterator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>executor</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <items>
                <item>dev</item>
                <item>test</item>
                <item>qa</item>
                <item>production</item>
                <item>pretest</item>
              </items>
              <pluginExecutors>
                <pluginExecutor>
                  <goal>single</goal>
                  <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                  </plugin>
                  <configuration>
                    <descriptors>
                      <descriptor>${project.basedir}/src/main/assembly/iterator.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                  </configuration>
                </pluginExecutor>
              </pluginExecutors>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

The [iterator-maven-plugin](https://github.com/khmarbaise/iterator-maven-plugin) is available via [maven central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Citerator-maven-plugin). I think you can adapt the above configuration/structure to your problem.

Comment: This was really a two-part question: refactoring out the common stuff in the assembly descriptors can be done with component descriptors: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/single/using-components.html also here: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/component.html

Comment: This might be a simpler alternative in the meantime: https://github.com/khmarbaise/multienv-maven-plugin

Answer (score 3):

Having messed with a similar problem for a long time, I got rid of tons of XML code, using the following workarounds:

1. Create the same zip archive for all the environments; resources should be extracted or accessed depending on environment (server's hostname, environment variables, etc.)
2. Create a single JAVA/Groovy class that will build all the necessary environment-specific assemblies and run it through maven-exec-plugin execution.

Comment: Groovy was the only reasonable solution in my case too.