# Maven: copy zipped resource subdirectories into target folder

Tags: java, maven, zip

I have a project with the following resources:

```
resources
  - directory1
  - directory2
```

I would like these to end up in the target folder as follows:

```
target
  - resources
     - directory1
     - directory2.zip
```

I know how to use the maven-resources-plugin to copy the raw resources of directory1 and exclude the raw resources of directory2, but how do I generate the zip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read the following article :

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html

This has the complete information for creating a zip artifact.

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful. After further research I also found this one which helped me very much: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19645070/1921560